# How do I install video.h for gstreamer on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gstreamer

I've followed [installation instruction](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c) to install gstreamer on Ubuntu 18, but still I can't compile this line from examples:

```
#include <gst/video/video.h>
```

gst folder is there, but video.h is missing. Here is output of **find /usr/include -name video.h**

```
/usr/include/linux/dvb/video.h
/usr/include/linux/usb/video.h
```

What package should I install to get **video.h**?

Comment: This question would be better received on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), which is part of the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Install the developer package with `sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev`. You may also need `libgstreamer1.0-dev`. They are missing from the Ubuntu list at [installation instruction](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html?gi-language=c). The Fedora list looks like it includes the developer packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the package with **apt-file**, it is **libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev**.